# Java HTTP server not working

Tags: java, http

I am hosting a webpage from home. I made my own HTTP server using Java. This is an SSCCE:

```
if(command.startsWith("GET"))
{
            //client is a socket on which I reply.
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
    String commule = command.split(" ");
    if(commule[0].equals("GET"))
    {
        if(commule[1].contains("."))
        {
            File file = new File(GEQO_SERVER_ROOT + commule[1].substring(1).replaceAll("%20", " "));
            if(file.exists())
            {
                OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
                InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);

                String response = new String();
                response += "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
                response += "Date: Thu, 08 Aug 2013 08:49:37 GMT\r\n";
                response += "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
                response += "Content-Length: " + file.length() + "\r\n";
                response += "Connection: keep-alive\r\n";
                response += "\r\n";
                pw.write(response); //Assume I already initialized pw as a PrintWriter
                                    pw.flush();
                copy(stream, out);
                stream.close();
                out.close();
            }
            else
            {
                pw.write("<html><h1>The request 404ed.</h1>");
                pw.write("<body>The requested URL <b>" + commule[1] + "</b> could not be found on this server.</body></html>");
                                    pw.flush();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(GEQO_SERVER_ROOT + commule[1].substring(1) + "main.html"));
            String sCurrentLine;
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                pw.print(sCurrentLine);
            }
            br.close();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        pw.println("Unrecognized HTTP command.");
    }
}
```

This is the main.html source :

`<html>`
`<title>Geqo Server</title>`
`<body>Geqo server online and functioning!</body>`
`</html>`

The issue is that when I try to access this page using Chrome, it displays correctly (At least when using 127.0.0.1). But when I tried accessing it on Firefox on 127.0.0.1, it works, but just gives me the html source. IE also only gives me the source. Can anyone tell me why Firefox and IE only show the source, instead of parsing it?

I think this contains some clues (Firebug screenshot) :

[image: Firebug screenshot]

My source seems to be coming in a `<pre>` tag. I donno why, but isn't that sort of the problem?

I port-forwarded. Here's the page guys : `http://110.172.170.83:17416/` (Sorry, Stackoverflow doesn't allows numerical links.)

EDIT : I found the problem. But before I explain, thanks to [Bart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2149440/bart) for the SSCCE, which I used to compare with my code. This is the problem : The `if` statement on the eighth line `if(commule[1].contains("."))` causes the code to skip the most of the code here. In that respective `else` block, there is even no command to send the headers. Thanks to [artbristol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116509/artbristol) for pointing that out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to be fine. Could be that the headers are not correct on your OS platform as for `\r\n` and Chrome makes some assumption.

Comment: I dont think so. I am on Windows 7, and moreover, it works on Chrome.

Comment: Using firebug in Firefox, the content-type that the response has for google.com is `text/html; charset=UTF-8`, try adding the charset, just to see what happens

Comment: Try to response only with `200` in the header.

Comment: Also fix the Date to : `"Date : " + new Date()` :D

Comment: @morgano, Did that, but the same problem persists.

Comment: @PeterMmm, Problem persists bro...

Comment: @Sw4Tish, Problem still persists...

Comment: @morgano, I checked using Firebug, I think I found the problem. I've updated my question. Please check.

Comment: @Hele what about those script and iframe tags? Do they come from your server?

Comment: Looks like you are not sending any headers at all. Chrome just assumes the correct Content-Type.

Comment: Yea yea of course, hmm try this at the end of your response just to see : "\r\n\r\n" instead of "\r\n", else try to send with a PrintStream and use the `.getBytes()` to send your body message in bytes, else (if you don't already do this) try the constructor PrintWriter(out, true) which auto-flushes your printer, else I can't help ^^

Comment: @Sw4Tish Tried everything brother, still the same problem :(

Comment: @Bart, Check my update. I have shown my initialization of Printwriter.

Comment: Hmm my poor tricks are a bit pointless but well it worths a try :D I made a HTTP server not so far ago and I never faced such a prob

Comment: @Sw4Tish, You made a HTTP server? Really? Thats awesome. Culd you maybe link me to the code, so that I can reverse engineer it and compare it with mine and try to solve the problem? Maybe you can just post it as an answer. I am am able to to id, I will accept your answer?

Comment: Yes, a little one ! I wish I could give you the code, but it's very subdivided because it has been done during my computer science studies and it's in french. However I still got the sources so I'm able to give you some snippets if you want to ^^

Comment: Yea, please send me anything you can. You can find my email ID on my profile or just post it as an answer :))

Comment: When I could, I'll write it there or send it by mail, no problem. One last thing, have you tried the Content-type : html/plain ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your printwriter isn't flushing (as Ernest pointed out), so no HTTP headers are being sent. Look at the result of connecting directly - it just returns the raw data, with no headers.

```
nc 110.172.170.83 17416
GET /

<html><title>Geqo Server</title><body>Geqo server online and functioning!</body></html>
```

Writing an HTTP server is *hard work*. Unless this is for an exercise, you should use a lightweight existing one, such as Jetty, or the built in Sun HTTP server in the JDK.

Edit - A `PrintWriter` really isn't appropriate for doing HTTP. It's designed to deal with line-by-line data such as a file being written to disk. It's also dependent on platform-specific settings for text encoding and line endings. Check the [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) for more details on how a proper HTTP server ought to work.

Comment: Yea, it's just an excercise. :)

Comment: +1 indeed, I tried it too. I don't believe you've added the "flush" call I suggested!

Comment: Check the updated code. I added flush. If you try to connect to my IP now, you can see the result. I am flushing.

Comment: Yup, your solution contained the answer, I just did'nt notice. Please check my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

There would appear to be some potential issues with buffering. You write some of your output to a `PrintWriter` wrapper around `out`, and other output directly to `out`. I would definitely add a call to `pw.flush()` after the `pw.write()` call.

Answer (score 1):

You enabled `autoFlush` with the second argument to

```
new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true)
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html

> Unlike the PrintStream class, if automatic flushing is enabled it will be done only when one of the println, printf, or format methods is invoked, rather than whenever a newline character happens to be output. These methods use the platform's own notion of line separator rather than the newline character.

So basically your `pw.write()` did not flush to the output stream. So all you need to do is replace

```
pw.write(response);
```

with

```
pw.println(response);
```

Comment: I created a [little test](http://pastebin.com/QjjvCqmx) as close as possible to your situation (simplified). This code printed out the HTML unparsed when `write` was called and the parsed version on `println`. Have you tried leaving out the `copy()` call and just print a simple string?

Comment: Your code seems to work, hmmmm...., but mine still does'nt. Hold on, running tests..

Answer (score 0):

You do not send any response header.

I can't find the definition of `pw` in your source code?

Comment: There is a comment after that saying that it is initialized. Please check the question.

Comment: My fault. Still it would be good to see how the PrintWriter is initialized.